# Array of UITextView's that interact with objects of the other classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I'm rather new to objective C and at the moment I'm trying to create one small project.
The task I want to accomplish is the following:

I've got the `UIViewController` for the screen of the game I'm creating. It has an `UIImageView` and a `UITextView` on it. What it does so far is that the latter one is moving towards the former one. And when their frames intersect (`CGRectIntersectsRect`) some actions happen.

What I want to achieve next is to create a specific class for `UITextviews`, so that there will be many of them created on the screen of `UIViewController` (I think array should be used here). And next I want every of them to be checking themselves, if they have an intersection with the `UIImageView` - than (again) something happens.

I've tried several ways like creating a mutable array, but every time I've some errors connected with variables of the original ViewController used inside of the new class (Hit).

The code I use for the one existing `UITextView`, that is created inside of `UIViewController`, is the following:

```
-(void)Moving{

HitR.center = CGPointMake(HitR.center.x+HitRX, HitR.center.y+HitRY);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(HitR.frame, Finish.frame)) {
 /*some actions here*/    
 }
}
```

etc

Can you help me to create these array of `UItextFields`, using their own class, tell them what to do with the help of properties like `UIimageview.frame` from the `ViewController` and then to place them on the screen.

P.S. I've read numerous articles about how to transfer variables from one class to another, but still failed to accomplish my aim.